# Keep getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED with NGINX conf

Tags: ssl, nginx, https

I keep getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile off;    

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        # server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


    server {

        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        add_header Allow "GET, HEAD" always;

         ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
         ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;


        if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD)$ ) {
            return 405;
        }

        return 200;

    }

}
```

it successfully redirects me from http:localhost to https:localhost, but all I see is this immediately:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Does anyone know why this is happening? is it my certs?

I am just using `localhost` right now, so it probably isn't firewall thing. Unfortunately, nothing shows up in the access or error logs which is frankly pretty sorry.

Comment: when I do `telnet localhost 443` I get connection refused as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer was I was using docker, and I needed to open up port `80` AND port `443`:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 -p 443:443 "$my_image"
```